# Projection with modulus less than one

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be an Hilbert Space, $X=Y\bigoplus Z$ where $Y$, $Z$ are both closed subspaces.

Let $P:X \rightarrow X$ $P(y+z)= y$ be the canonical projection, then

$||P|| \leq 1 \implies  Y=Z^{\bot}$

This should be quite standard but the proof provided by my lecture does not convince me, they argue in the following way, let $\zeta\in \mathbb{C} $ then 
$$||y+\zeta z||^2 = ||y||^2 + |\zeta|^2 ||z||^2+ \Re\langle y, \zeta z\rangle  = ||P(y+\zeta z)||^2 + |\zeta|^2 ||z||^2+ \Re\langle y, \zeta z\rangle   $$

So by the bound on the norm

$$|\zeta|^2 ||z||^2+ \Re\langle y, \zeta z\rangle \geq 0$$

Since this houlds for all $\zeta$ they conclude that $\langle y,z\rangle=0$

How does this follow?

Alternatively, could you indicate a valid proof?

Thanks

Comment: there is a typo: it should be $2 \Re \langle y,\zeta z\rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to divide the inequality
$$
|\zeta|^2 \|z\|^2 + 2\Re \langle y ,\zeta z\rangle \ge0
$$
by $\zeta$ for suitable values of $\zeta$.

First, take $\zeta\in \mathbb R$, $\zeta> 0$, then divide by $\zeta$, which gives 
$$
|\zeta| \|z\|^2 + 2\Re \langle y , z\rangle \ge0,
$$
then $\zeta\searrow 0$. Do the same for a negative $\zeta$. At the end, 
$\Re \langle y ,\zeta z\rangle=0$ is proved.

Then do the same for $\zeta = i\cdot t$, $t\ne 0$, $t\in \mathbb R$. This gives 
$\Im \langle y ,\zeta z\rangle=0$.